# Properties of difference of projections

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be real square matrix of order $\geq 6$ and $B = I - 2A$. Which of the following claims is (are) true?

1. If A is a projection, then B is orthogonal.
2. If A is a projection, then B is non-singular.
3. If A is an orthogonal projection, then B is orthogonal.

Could you please help me? I know that if A is a projection, then I-A is a projection as well.

Comment: Why is the order of the matrix relevant here?

Comment: May be to make it harder to create counterexamples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be a projection. Then we have the following identities:

$$ im A\cap \ker A= \{0\},\quad \ker (I-A)=im (A),\quad \ker A= im (I-A),$$
$$\Bbb R^n = \ker A\oplus \ker (I-A) = im(A)\oplus im (I-A)$$
$$A=A^2$$

One can say that $B$ is a reflection by $\ker A$ in the direction of $im(A)$.

1. Let $v$ be a vector and $Bv=0$. The $$0=Bv = (I-A)v - Av\in  im(A)\oplus im (I-A).$$ Therefore by the properties of a decomposition of $\Bbb R^n$ in a direct sum of two subspaces we conclude that necessarily $(I-A)v=Av=0$ and thus $v=0$. Hence $B$ is non-singular.
2. If $A$ is an orthogonal projection, then $A=A^*$ and $BB^* = (I-2A)(I-2A)^*=(I-2A)^2=I-4A+4A^2=I$, hence $B$ is an orthogonal matrix.
3. If $A$ is not orthogonal, you can easily build $A$ - a projection in $\Bbb R^6$ such that $\ker A = \{x\in\Bbb R^6,\,x_1=0\}$ and $im (A) = \{x\in\Bbb R^6,\,x_1=x_2=\dots=x_6\}$ and then check that $B$ is not orthogonal.

Comment: (2) turns out to be so easy! thank you!